# How to get function of both position values: Fixed and Absolute?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fullscreen background image. I also have a pop-out sidebar.

When the sidebar pops out it re-sizes the background image smaller so as to not cut it off by covering over it. When the sidebar is retracted then the image enlarges back.

I can only get this effect if the background image has a position value of absolute. However that value also doesn't let you scroll without the background ending and getting blank space or having to repeat the image to fill the blank space.

When I make the position value fixed then it solved the blank space issue, but no longer re-sizes the background image when you open the sidebar, it covers up part of the background as you'd expect.

How do I get the effects of both the position values of Fixed and Absolute? I want it to scroll indefinitely without having to duplicate the image, but also re-size when the sidebar is opened.

Here is the theme I'm using that illustrates my problem: http://themes.themolitor.com/wpzoom/2011/04/first-blog-post-title/

```
$(function() {
 $('#openSidebar').click(function() {

     if ( $('#sidebar').width() == 300 ) {
         var y = window.innerWidth;
         $("#imageContainer").width(y-300);
     }
     else  {
         $('#sidebar').width(0);
         $('#imageContainer').width("100%"); 
     }
  });



 $('#closeSidebar').click(function() {

     if ( $('#sidebar').width() == 300 ) {
         var y = window.innerWidth;
         $("#imageContainer").width(y);
     }
     else  {
         $('#sidebar').width(0);
         $('#imageContainer').width("100%"); 
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually thats easier. Obviously you will have a button that opens your sidebar when you click it. Considering your sidebar is on the right (like your example theme) you just need to resize bg's width and leave height as it is. So this is the code:

```
document.getElementById("sidebar-button").addEventListener("click", doStuff, false);

doStuff = function() {
   var sb = document.getElementById("sidebar");
   var bgnd = document.getElementById("bg");

   if ( sb.style.width == 0 ) {
       sb.style.width = "300px";
       var y = window.innerWidth;
       bgnd.style.width = y - 300 + "px";
   }

   else {
       sb.style.width = "0px";
       bgnd.style.width = "100%";  
   }
};
```

But you still need the the idea of window.onresize so you can adjust bg's width correctly.

EDIT:

```
$(function() {
     $('#sidebar-button').click(function() {

         if ( $('#sidebar').width() == 0 ) {
             $('#sidebar').width( 300 );
             var y = window.innerWidth;
             $("#bg").width(y-300);
         }
         else  {
             $('#sidebar').width(0);
             $('#bg').width("100%"); 
         }
      });
});
```

I just tested and works just fine, the only difference is that it use jQuery.

Comment: That didn't work. I replaced the ID's with the valid ones and nothing happened.

Comment: Well you re right it should be (sb.style == 0) and not <. Anyway I will edit it with a new one.

Comment: Mm, didn't work. I'll ad what I put on the original post. Thanks for your help btw. Also with that code when I close the sidebar a blank black area the same size as the sidebar is left and doesn't go away.

Comment: I figured it out, I duplicated a couple times you code and fiddled with it some. I'll post it above so you can see.

Comment: The $(function() { }); there is no need to use it twice. Just ecnlose all your function in the first one

Answer (score 0):

Well here is an example:

Lets say the background is a div with id #bg then all you have to do is to resize the bg when the window is resized using javascript considering when your window starts to be scrollable. If for example your windows starts to be X-scrollable when its width is 800px or less and Y-Scrollable when its height is 500px:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    if ( window.width < 800 ) document.getElementById("#bg").style.width = "800px";
    else document.getElementById(#bg).style.width = "100%";

    if ( window.height < 500 ) document.getElementById("#bg").style.height = "500px";
    else document.getElementById("#bg").style.height = "100%";
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I think you almost have it. I need something that says: "If sidebar is opened reduce the width and height by x percent" (separately) And then the reverse: "if sidebar is closed increase..." How would that be done?

Comment: Because it isn't the screen being re-sized. So i need something like .onclick(openSidebar) {reduce background img width & height 5%} and then .onclick(closeSidebar) {increase background img width & height 5%}